# comment all lines not working in VS code - Pinescript V5

Tags: visual-studio-code, pine-script-v5

**Summary:**

- when I select multiple lines and use control / to comment them out,
  nothing happens

**What I've tried:**

- I changed my keyboard version to english - it was already set to
  english
- I edited my commands - changed it to control, shift, / -    still not
  working

**Additional notes:**

- I'm using pinescript V5 as my language.  not sure if this makes a
  difference.  I can comment out multiple lines fine in pine editor in
  tradingview.